# Siverlight 4 Deployment : WCF RIA Services - “Not Found” Error Message

Tags: silverlight, deployment, wcf-ria-services, fiddler

I have some issues deploying a Silverlight 4 application on a remote server machine.  My application consist a Cosmopolitan theme (a master/child page model) that connected with 2 services to retrieve specific information.

The first service is pretty simple. It is an asmx service that sends back the User Logon name to the Silverlight application. 
The second one is a LinqToSQL service that relay some information to some autocompletebox and search tool.

I have developed the application on my machine using a local SQL server. When I am testing locally with an address type like this one (http://localhost:4080), it is working perfectly. But when deploying on the server using the domain name, it is giving the error saying that the remote server returned an error: NotFound.

I followed and review every steps on of deployment but I still have a problem. I try by all means to find a solution to this problem. Of course go through the list of prerequisites provided on these sites:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

First, I tried myself to deploy the application without having to disturb my network administrators that by installing the required dll’s in the Bin directory of my project. I have installed those 3 dll’s (System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll and Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.LinqToSql.dll).  Of course, nothing worked.

I then ask the network administrator to install the WCF RIA services. Does he have to configure something other than installing the WCF RIA services? Is this service including the Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.LinqToSql.dll.

I suspect that my problem comes from a configurations file: ServiceReferences.ClientConfig or Web.config. But I have included the exact same information from the MSDN site of deployment so I do not see where my problem might be. Am I using the wrong technique to publish the project?  I am publishing the site using the File System method and then after modifying the config file to point to the right domain name.

I am able to reach the services by typing the http://domainname/ MeritService1.svc. It is telling me that I can test with the svcutil.exe or slsvcutil.exe. Will I lose a lot of time testing this?

By the way, Fiddler does not give much information accept a 500 error code.

It seems that many developers have the same problem themselves but I do not know where to aim! Anybody have a clue?

Here are the specs:

Local  machine:  Windows XP,

Browser: IE8 with Silverlight

Server Machine: Windows 2003 with IIS 6, .NET 4.0 and WFC RIA installed.

Answer (score 1):

The following link may be of some help

[WCF RIA Services - “Not Found” Error Message](http://blogs.objectsharp.com/blogs/dan/archive/2010/04/13/wcf-ria-services-not-found-error-message.aspx)

Comment: I really think my problem is related to the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig. Anybody know if I only need to change the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig endpoint from http://localhost:4080 to http://domainename.com to make it work? Or do I need to change it everywhere in the solution. In the Disco file, the Wsdl files, for example?